# Append value to key with multiple values in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, split, key

I have a textarea with structure like this:

```
1|title1|value2
1|title3|value4
1|...
3|title5|value6
```

My goal is to end up with a key-multiple value pair, such that I can output each value on demand (in a for loop) based on its order if I know the key.

e.g.

```
myArray[1][0][0] = title1
myArray[1][1][1] = value4
myArray[3][0][0] = title5
```

I can split up the textarea starting with something like this to create an object of lines, but it does not incorporate the third dimension of duplicate numbers.

```
var audioArray = {};
var audioTextareaValue = document.getElementById('audioTextarea').value;
    audioTextareaValue.split('\n').forEach(function(x){
    var arr = x.split('|');
    arr[1] && (audioArray[arr[0]] = [arr[1],arr[2]]);
});
```

Comment: `myArray[1][1][1] = value4` can you explain how you will end up like this

Comment: I'm not saying that `myArray[1][1][1] = value4` is real code-- just looking for a way to specify for example, value4 in a for loop so I can format title + value on a per-number basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to check if you already have the property on your audioArray (which is an object) and then push the new array to the list based on the key.

```
var audioDict = {};
var audioTextareaValue = document.getElementById('audioTextarea').value;

audioTextareaValue.split('\n').forEach(function(x){
   var arr = x.split('|');

   if ( !arr[0] ){
     return;
   }

   if (audioDict.hasOwnProperty(arr[0])) {
     audioDict[arr[0]].push([arr[1], arr[2]]);
   } else {
     audioDict[arr[0]] = [[arr[1], arr[2]]];
   }

});
```

[demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qbf3g4v/)